# How to read one txt file into several textboxes by a button(in different order)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, readfile

For example: if my txt file's contents is  aaa|bbb|ccc. I'd like to use a button to distribute aaa to textbox2, bbb to textbox5, cccto textbox3 . So How to make it? I have try lots of ways to solve it ,but it still doesn't work.Please~

Comment: post your code what you have tried and where you stuck.....

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far so that others can help you do fix the blocking issue. According to me, you should be able to do this using substring function if the text file is uniform in data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your text file content like this.

```
aaaa|bbb|cccc
dddd|eee|ffff
```

then you can try this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
        textBox2.Multiline = true;
        textBox3.Multiline = true;
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
       var lines =   File.ReadAllLines("D:\\sample.txt");
       foreach (var line in lines) 
       {

           var splits = line.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
           if (splits.Length > 2) {
               sb1.Append(splits[0] + Environment.NewLine);
               sb2.Append(splits[1] + Environment.NewLine);
               sb3.Append(splits[2] + Environment.NewLine);
           }


       }
       textBox1.Text = sb1.ToString();
       textBox2.Text = sb2.ToString();
       textBox3.Text = sb3.ToString();
    }
```

out will be like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank u very much! I'll try it later

Comment: var lines =   File.ReadAllLines("D:\\sample.txt"); May i ask why this line will jump out a error ?

Comment: you should set the path of your text file here.

Comment: or make sure  your Drive "D" conttains a file with the name of "Sample.txt"

Comment: thank u veryvery much again.U helped me to solve big prob for me :))